# Update Location data using android app in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing a simple android app in which i need to create maps and track location just like Uber... I am using firebase as my database that will store user's location.
To store the location I created a service that is invoked when my MainActivity is called
The problem i am facing is that the location is getting updated only once in the database i.e when the location is changed it does not gets updated in the database for that i have to restart the application for the new location to get updated.

Here's the code of onLocationChanged method in my location Service

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
Log.d("lam", "onLocationChanged:lam "+location.getLatitude()); //The log gets updated but not the values in database

Map<String,Object> taskMap=new HashMap<>();
taskMap.put("Latitude",location.getLatitude());
taskMap.put("Longitude",location.getLongitude());
try{                
    urlCurrenUser.updateChildren(taskMap);//urlCurrentUser is the path to database
   }catch(Exception e){}
                }
```

I also tried

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
Log.d("lam", "onLocationChanged:lam "+location.getLatitude()); //The log gets updated but not the values in database
 try {
urlCurrenUser.child("Lattitude").setValue(location.getLattitude());
urlCurrenUser.child("Longitude").setValue(location.getLongitude());
}catch (Exception e){}
```

I have called the service in the onCreate() of my main activity

Edit 
I think there is a problem in my urlCurrentUser (reference to the database) when the app starts at first attempt the location gets updated in the database but when the location changes and again the code is invoked to update the new coordinates it gives an exception i.e

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.firebase.client.Firebase
>   com.firebase.client.Firebase.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference

I just can't understand how to solve this 
Here's a snapshot of my database structure 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MBW8.png)

Database Reference Code

```
urlCurrenUser = new Firebase(URL).child("users").child(authData.getUid());
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the latest [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) you were working with an old API version.

> 1 - Make sure you have configured the right google service JSON file
>   that downloaded from the firebase project console.
>
> 2 - By default, read and write access to your database is restricted so
>   only authenticated users can read or write data. To get started
>   without setting up [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), you can [configure your
>   rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules) for public access. This does make your database open to
>   anyone, even people not using your app, so be sure to restrict your
>   database again when you set up authentication.
>
> 3 - Follow precisely the well-documented [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) to write and read
>   data from firebase database.